# error en formulario dinamico con Select en laravel Collective

Tags: laravel

Hola Buen día estoy intentando implementar un formulario con laravel collective pero me sale el error que el select no agarra el value:

*QueryException in Connection.php line 770:
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'ciudad' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `clientes`*

Seguro que estoy poniendo mal los valores en el select pero no se cómo colocarlos correctamente.
Dejo esta parte del de código del formulario donde esta el select.

```html
<div class="row">
   <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-offset-xs-8 col-sm-4 col-offset-sm-8">
    {!! Form::text('address_number',$cliente->address_number,['class'=> 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'número de puerta'])!!}
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-xs col-md-4">

    {!!Form::select('ciudad', $cliente->ciudad,['1' => 'ciudad1', '2' => 'ciudad2'], null,
             [
                'class' => 'form-group',
                'placeholder' => 'Ciudad...',

             ])
    !!}


   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-4">
    {!! Form::text('pais',$cliente->pais,['class'=> 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'País'])!!}
   </div>
  </div>
```

Espero me puedan ayuda.

Gracias

El codigo que recibe el formulario es el siguiente:

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    $cliente = New Cliente;

    $cliente->id = $request->id;
    $cliente->name = $request->name;
    $cliente->documento = $request->documento;

    $cliente->tipo_de_negocio = $request->tipo_de_negocio;
    $cliente->email = $request->email;
    $cliente->address = $request->address;
    $cliente->address_number = $request->address_number;
    $cliente->ciudad = $request->ciudad;
    $cliente->pais = $request->pais;
    $cliente->telephone1 = $request->telephone1;
    $cliente->telephone2 = $request->telephone2;
    $cliente->user_id = Auth::user()->id;

    if($cliente->save()){
        return redirect('/clientes');
    }else{
        return view('clientes.create',['cliente'=>$cliente]);
    }
```

por las dudas pongo el formulario completo:

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => $url,'method' => $method ])!!}



<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::text('name',$cliente->name,['class'=> 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Nombre'])!!}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
     DNI  {!! Form::radio('documento', 'DNI' , false,[$cliente->documento => 'documento']) !!}
     RUC  {!! Form::radio('documento', 'RUC' , false,[$cliente->documento => 'documento']) !!}
</div>

<!--div class="form-group">

    {!!Form::select("documento",['DNI' => 'DNI', 'RUC' => 'RUC'], null,
             [
                "class" => "form-group",
                "placeholder" => "Documento"
             ])
    !!}
</div-->

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::text('tipo_de_negocio',$cliente->tipo_de_negocio,['class'=> 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Tipo de Negocio'])!!}
</div>

<div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            {!! Form::text('id',$cliente->id,['class'=> 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Ruc o Dni'])!!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            {!! Form::text('email',$cliente->email,['class'=> 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Email'])!!}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix">
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::text('address',$cliente->address,['class'=> 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Dirección'])!!}
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-offset-xs-8 col-sm-4 col-offset-sm-8">
            {!! Form::text('address_number',$cliente->address_number,['class'=> 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'número de puerta'])!!}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-xs col-md-4">

            {!!Form::select('ciudad',['1' => 'ciudad1', '2' => 'ciudad2'], null,
         [
            'class' => 'form-group',
            'placeholder' => 'Ciudad...',
             $cliente =>'ciudad'

         ])
            !!}


        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-4">
            {!! Form::text('pais',$cliente->pais,['class'=> 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'País'])!!}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-xs col-md-4">
            {!! Form::text('telephone1',$cliente->telephone1,['class'=> 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Teléfono1'])!!}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-4">
            {!! Form::text('telephone2',$cliente->telephone2,['class'=> 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Teléfono2'])!!}
        </div>

<div class="form-group text-right">
    <a href="{{url('/clientes')}}">Regresar al Listado de Clientes</a>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-success">
</div>
{!! Form::close()!!}
```

Bueno te comento que me funcionaba bien, guardaba los datos en la base hasta que quise implementar el select dropdown, la verdad que no tengo claro como implementarlo osea donde colocarle la variable como a los demas campos. Bueno espero se entienda. Saludos

Comment: ¿Cuándo aparece ese error? al entrar al formulario o al enviarlo

Comment: hola buenos días, me aparece al enviarlo

Comment: Puedes poner el código del post que recibe los datos del formulario.

Comment: Hola Víctor, lo actualicé, como comento me funcionaba hasta que quise implementar el select no se bien donde poner la variable. y creo que por eso saca el error, bueno eso creo. Estaré atento. Saludos

Comment: Lo solucione: {!!Form::select('ciudad',['Ciudad1' => 'Ciudad1', 'Ciudad2' => 'Ciudad2'], null,
             [
              $cliente->ciudad,
                'class' => 'form-group',
                'placeholder' => 'Ciudad...',

             ])
    !!}

Comment: Que bueno que lo resolviste y no es que tenga que ver con el problema pero recomendaría ya no usar Laravel Collective, aparte de que ya no tiene soporte, no tiene ninguna ventaja de rendimiento o algún aspecto positivo del por qué usarlo, con las directivas de laravel que ya trae debería de ser más que suficiente...

Comment: Gracias Aarón, de verdad valoro mucho tu comentario. Saludos